# Semantic UI dropdown selection content from API

Tags: javascript, html, json, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI 2.0 and trying to use data returned from its [API](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage) to build the options inside my dropdown.

For the dropdown itself, I am using a code that is pratically the same as [this](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-selection) code shown in Semantic UI's documentation:

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown select-city">
  <input type="hidden" name="city">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select City</div>
</div>
```

I have a service that returns json-formatted cities, then Semantic UI shows in the console that the result was successful with all 261 cities:

```
"Using specified url"   ["/cities/"]    1648
"Querying URL"  ["/cities/"]    0
"Sending request"   [undefined, "get"]  0
"Successful API Response"   [Object { success=true, results=[261]}]
```

The /cities endpoint return a json formatted as:

```
{"success":true,"results":[{"description":"Opole","data-value":1},{"description":"Wrocław","data-value":2},{"description":"Warszawa","data-value":3},{"description":"Budapest","data-value":4},{"description":"Köln","data-value":5}, ...]}
```

It looks like that Semantic UI does not directly understand the format of the json.

I've tried many formats of json attributes, even tried to change a bit the html. For instance, tried to add an empty `<div class="menu">` in the bottom of the select, hoping that Semantic UI would fill it in, e.g.,:

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown select-city">
  <input type="hidden" name="city">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select City</div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to match the format of the attributes with the ones from the [example](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-selection), e.g., using "data-value" attribute.

But it did not work either, I've seen Semantic UI [checks for that](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/definitions/modules/dropdown.js#L266) in the source code, so it does not make any difference. At the end, my problem persists and no items are inserted into the dropdown selection.

Comment: How exactly are you fetching this data? Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay to respond how I am fetching this data. Previously I was using the default .api function within semantic-ui. Since it was not working, now I am using a ajax call and filling up the menu by myself, instead of using the automatic process of semantic-ui api. I will try to redo the code I was using before and I will update the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without you posting the code that you're using I'm taking a bit of a stab here, but the `dropdown` expects data results to be keyed as `{ name: "Item 1", value: "value1" }` as is explained in the [relevant part of the documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#remote-content).

If you have a different field names then you can provide a `fields` structure in the settings to override these:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    fields: { name: "description", value: "data-value" },
    apiSettings: {
        mockResponse: {
            success: true,
            results: [
                {"description":"Opole","data-value":1},
                {"description":"Wrocław","data-value":2},
                {"description":"Warszawa","data-value":3},
                {"description":"Budapest","data-value":4},
                {"description":"Köln","data-value":5}
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

The minimum HTML required is:

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown">
    <div class="text">Search</div>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown">
    <input class="search"></input>
</div>
```

The empty `<div class="menu"></div>` is automatically inserted, but an `<input class="search"></input>` is required and is only automatically inserted if you already have a `<div class="text"></div>` element.

Note however that, in what I believe to be a fault with the dropdown behaviour, **it will not load the data until you start typing into the search field** and so just clicking on the dropdown icon is not sufficient.

Comment: Great! That was the problem over here. Setting the 'fields' hash did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: An issue with this answer is that the dropdown stopped searching, e.g.,: https://jsfiddle.net/nLghbfs8/ by start typing "K" does filter "Koln". Not sure why.

Comment: @Eduardo When using the API interface it expects the API query to do the filtering for it.  You can look at using `mockResponseAsync` and find the `query` in the settings object for testing purposes, but otherwise you need your server to filter on the query term.

Comment: ah, ok, I see. Thanks for the clarification. I will update my server-side code accordingly so it can work as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi all, I am facing the same issue here, search is not working anymore...@Parakleta: what does it mean that I have to set my server to filter on the query term? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LauraSilvani The documentation states that the URL in the `apiSettings` will be queried for the filtered response (i.e. the `{query}` component of the URL) and your server must return a compliant JSON response.  Go to the linked documentation page, open the network devtools on your browser and observe the requests/responses as you type.

Comment: @Parakleta: first of all, thanks for replying. My issue is that I do not have a JSON response formatted with 'name' and 'value' pairs, so I am currently using onResponse callback to adjust its format, as per documentation http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage (see Modifying Response JSON). I have opened a question here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610849 with code example